# C# Serial Communication for Multi COM Ports

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

I want to communicate two devices with my computer using RS232 communication.I want to send hex commands  from my computer to devices. I have 2 buttons on my interface. When I press the first button, I will send a code to the first device, and when I press the second button, I will send a code to the second device.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace _2button
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(); 
            sp.PortName = "COM1"; 
            sp.BaudRate = 19200;  
            sp.DataBits = 8; 
            sp.Parity = Parity.None; 
            sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            //SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM1",9600,Parity.None,8,StopBits.One);
            sp.Open();
            sp.Write(new byte[] { }, 0, 10); 
            sp.Close();
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
            sp.PortName = "COM2";
            sp.BaudRate = 19200;
            sp.DataBits = 8;
            sp.Parity = Parity.None;
            sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            //SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM2",9600,Parity.None,8,StopBits.One);
            sp.Open();
            sp.Write(new byte[] {  }, 0, 10); 
            sp.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I send the command (same or different) for two different COM (COM1 and COM2) ports?

How can I send the same command to different com ports with a single button?

Comment: First, figures and source code can be presented and described in question articles rather than links to other sites. Please write the source code in text. And opening/closing the COM port every time you send a command is bad behavior. It's a good idea to open both COM ports when you start a program or start a large chunk of functionality, and close both COM ports when you exit a program or stop a large chunk of functionality. If you follow your request, all you have to do is send the commands in turn using each SerialPort object that is already open in one button click event.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for your reply. I have included the source code as text. How can I activate SerialPort for different COM ports when I start the program? The properties of the COM ports (BaudRate, Databits, Parity, Stopbits) are generally the same. How can I check the messages that will go to different COM ports after activating the serial port? So is there a command where I can choose which message to send for which port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think simply, you should do the following.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort sp1 = new SerialPort();
        SerialPort sp2 = new SerialPort();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OpenCOM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!sp1.IsOpen)
            {
                sp1.PortName = "COM1";
                sp1.BaudRate = 19200;
                sp1.DataBits = 8;
                sp1.Parity = Parity.None;
                sp1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                sp1.Open();
            }
            if (!sp2.IsOpen)
            {
                sp2.PortName = "COM2";
                sp2.BaudRate = 19200;
                sp2.DataBits = 8;
                sp2.Parity = Parity.None;
                sp2.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                sp2.Open();
            }
        }

        private void CloseCOM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sp1.IsOpen)
            {
                sp1.Close();
            }
            if (sp2.IsOpen)
            {
                sp2.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sp1.Write(new byte[] { 0x06, 0x14, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x34, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x5D }, 0, 10); //cmd = 0x06 0x14 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x34 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x5D
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sp2.Write(new byte[] { 0x06, 0x14, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x34, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x5E }, 0, 10); //cmd = 0x06 0x14 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x34 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x5E
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // same
            sp1.Write(new byte[] { 0x06, 0x14, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x34, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x5D }, 0, 10); //cmd = 0x06 0x14 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x34 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x5D
            sp2.Write(new byte[] { 0x06, 0x14, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x34, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x5D }, 0, 10); //cmd = 0x06 0x14 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x34 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x5D
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // different
            sp1.Write(new byte[] { 0x06, 0x14, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x34, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x5D }, 0, 10); //cmd = 0x06 0x14 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x34 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x5D
            sp2.Write(new byte[] { 0x06, 0x14, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x34, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x5E }, 0, 10); //cmd = 0x06 0x14 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x34 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x5E
        }
    }
```